# When Zacchaeus was granted Salvation by Jesus is this equivalent to "Being Born Again?" John 3:6

Tags: jesus, soteriology

Zacchaeus was granted salvation by the Messiah Jesus himself according to Luke 19:9. This incident occurred before Jesus died for the salvation of the human race.

Luke 19:9 KJV

> And Jesus said unto him, This day is salvation come to this house, forsomuch as he also is a son of Abraham.

Is it possible that Zacchaeus looked forward to Jesus' death at Calvary, or was this fact still unknown or not perceived by the "Lost sheep of Israel?"

Did Zacchaeus become **born again** on that day? Or did he need to wait until Pentecost?

Comment: Welcome to SE-BH. You are asking three questions, here, regarding Zacchaeus' precise faith, the perception of Jewish believers during the transition from one covenant to another, and whether 'salvation' is exactly the same (in time and experience) as 'being born again'.  These are all good and important questions and are touched on in many archived questions on this site. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 0):

I only discuss whether "Salvation" is equivalent to "being born again".

In John 3:3, Jesus told Nicodemus that *"no one can see the kingdom of God unless they are born again"*. The term "again" in this context is translated from the Greek word ἄνωθεν (anóthen Strong's 509), which carries multiple nuances according to Strong's Concordance: *(a) from above, from heaven, (b) from the beginning, from their origin (source), from of old, (c) again, anew.* This underscores that our first birth is physical, emerging from the waters of our mother's womb, whereas the rebirth Jesus speaks of is of a different nature.

Nicodemus, puzzled by the concept of being born a second time, prompts Jesus to elaborate in John 3:5, where He states, *"Very truly I tell you, no one can enter the kingdom of God unless they are born of water and the Spirit"*. This clarifies that the rebirth Jesus refers to is not a physical rebirth, but a spiritual one, initiated from above - symbolized through water, representing the words of God, and actualized by the Holy Spirit.

Salvation is a divine gift of redemption, freely extended from God to humanity. While it might seem synonymous with being "born again", the two concepts are intricately related yet distinct. Salvation is indeed God's sovereign gift, contingent upon His will. Conversely, being "born again" involves an individual's active decision to yield to God, renouncing sin with resolute determination. Paul said in Philippians 3:7-8

> 7 But whatever were gains to me I now consider loss for the sake of Christ. 8 What is more, I consider everything a loss because of the surpassing worth of knowing Christ Jesus my Lord, for whose sake I have lost all things. **I consider them garbage, that I may gain Christ.**

The story of Jesus and Zacchaeus further illustrates this distinction. Jesus announces that salvation had come to Zacchaeus's house, following his repentance and commitment to make amends for his wrongdoings (Luke 19:8-9). This narrative exemplifies that "Salvation" is indeed a gift, yet it is closely tied to the process of being "born again" - an integral transformation marking a personal and communal return to righteousness.

Answer (score -2):

> “Behold, half of my possessions, Lord, I shall give to the poor, and if I have extorted anything from anyone I shall repay it four times over.” Jesus said to him, “Today salvation has come to this house because
> this man too is a descendant of Abraham. 10 For the Son of Man has
> come to seek and to save what was lost.”

The implication here is that Zacchaeus and his family have returned to fold of Judaism. As a tax collector, Zacchaeus vowed to stop oppressing his fellow Jews and even promised to give half of what he owned to the poor and pay four times what he owed to those he may have extorted. His repentance has delivered him from his sinful ways. Note that Jesus does not actually "grant" salvation here. It comes to Zacchaeus by virtue of his changing his ways. The word is used here in a similar sense to its use in the Psalms and other OT scriptures, where it means "deliverance" - something many attained prior to Jesus' coming - rather than the Christian idea of regeneration.

This was great news for Zacchaeus and his neighbors, and Jesus rejoiced in it. However, it is not the same thing that the Gospel of John refers to when it reports Jesus speaking about the need for rebirth.

John 3

> Rabbi, we know that you are a teacher who has come from God, for no
> one can do these signs that you are doing unless God is with him.” 3
> Jesus answered and said to him, “Amen, amen, I say to you, no one can
> see the kingdom of God without being born from above.”

The [historical Nicodemus](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/11526-nicodemus-nakdimon-ben-gorion) was famous for his generosity and love of peace. In other words, he was already doing what Zacchaeus did after repenting. Yet Jesus told him he needed to be "born from above." In John's gospel, one does not attain eternal life by loving God and one's neighbor  as the other gospels teach (Luke 10:24-28). Eternal life comes only by partaking in the sacraments:

John 6:53-54

> Jesus said to them, “Amen, amen, I say to you, unless you eat the flesh of the Son of Man and drink his blood, you do not have life within you.  Whoever eats my flesh and drinks my blood has eternal life, and I will
> raise him on the last day.

**Conclusion**: John's Gospel does not directly address the issue of the Pentecost experience, but it implies that a person such as Zacchaeus would need to wait until he could partake in the sacraments before attaining eternal life.

Comment: Zacchaeus believed, and it was counted to him for righteousness. Just like Abraham.

Comment: Given that the repentant thief on a cross next to Jesus expressed his faith in Jesus and his kingdom, Jesus promised him they would both be in paradise, and the chap died without any baptism, or receipt of any sacraments, should not your last sentence reflect that anomaly? No down-votes from me, though!